# asp:UpdateProgress - suppressing the line-break

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I've started working with ASP.net AJAX (finally ☺). and I've got an update panel together with a asp:UpdateProgress. My Problem: The UpdateProgress always forces a line-break, because it renders out as a div-tag.

Is there any way to force it being a span instead? I want to display it on the same line as some other controls without having to use a table or even *shudders* absolute positioning in CSS.

I'm stuck with ASP.net AJAX 1.0 and .net 3.0 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just blogged about my own solution to this problem.
http://www.joeaudette.com/solving-the-aspnet-updateprogress-div-problem.aspx

What I did was borrow the UpdateProgress control from the Mono project and modified it to render as a span instead of a div. I also copied an modifed the ms-ajax javascript associated with the control and modified it to toggle between display:inline and display:none instead of using display:block

There is a .zip file linked in my post which contains the modified files.

Comment: I'm changing the accepted Answer (sorry Steven!) because this approach worked better. I've published the source to my UpdateProgressEx Control: http://www.stum.de/2010/01/28/an-asp-net-ajax-updateprogress-that-can-render-inline/

Answer (score 10):

simply place your UpdateProgress inside a span with style="position:absolute;"

Comment: This works great.  You'll need to set the DynamicLayout property to false to get this to work.

Answer (score 8):

I've had the same issue. There is no easy way to tell the updateProgress to render inline. You would be better off to roll your own updateProgress element. You can add a beginRequest listener and endRequest listener to show and hide the element you want to display inline. Here is simple page which shows how to do it:

**aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>


    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="btnTest_OnClick" />
        </ContentTemplate>    
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <img id="loadingImg" src="../../../images/loading.gif" style="display:none;"/><span>Some Inline text</span>

    <script>

        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(function(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_postBackElement().id == "btnTest") {
                document.getElementById("loadingImg").style.display = "inline";
            }
        });


        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(sender, args) {
            if (document.getElementById("loadingImg").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("loadingImg").style.display = "none";
            }
        });

    </script>

    </div>
</form>
```

**cs**

```
public partial class updateProgressTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnTest_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        this.lblTest.Text = "I was changed on the server! Yay!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution:
In CSS

```
.progress[style*="display: block;"] {
     display:inline !important;
}
```

And ASP

```
<asp:UpdateProgress  class="progress" ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 1):

A better and simplest way is use UpdateProgress inside UpdatePanel with span. I've tested this and work properly in IE, FF, Chrome browsers. like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        ..........
        <span style="position:absolute;">
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server"
                AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
                    <ProgressTemplate>
                        <img alt="please wait..."src="/Images/progress-dots.gif" />
                    </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress> 
        </span> 
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply `float:left` to your label/textbox etc. 
Like this:

in the header:

```
<style type="text/css">
.tbx 
{
    float:left;
}
```

in the body:

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="tbx" .... />
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to wrap it as follows...

```
<div class="load-inline">LOADER HERE</div>
```

And in my CSS I use...

```
.load-inline {display:inline-block}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make a div inline like this:

```
<div style="display:inline">stuff</div>
```

I'm skeptical of it rendering the div for you though...  I don't remember having this problem on my pages...